# How can I config ksqldb to understand binary proto-buffer message in kafka?

Tags: ksqldb

I want to use ksqldb to do some query on the streamed data encoded in proto-buffer format.
But I don't have a clue how to achieve it. What if the binary message data is plain c struct, how to decode the c-struct messages and apply queries on the stream data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ksqlDB supports Protobuf that's been [serialised using the Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format) format. To specify your data as protobuf use `FORMAT='PROTOBUF'` e.g.

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_stream
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', 
        FORMAT='PROTOBUF');
```

The schema itself is fetched from the Schema Registry.

For more details see https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/